# Replace empty values in list of dictionaries by corresponding value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a list of dictionaries with missing values. I want to replace the empty value with the corresponding value by the more efficient way.

Input:

```
[
    {"Host": "dailymotion", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "youtube", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "Vimeo", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://vimeo.com/42399207"},
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {"Host": "dailymotion", "Url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox"},
    {"Host": "youtube", "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0"},
    {"Host": "Vimeo", "Url": "https://vimeo.com/42399207"},
]
```

Comment: How did you get this dictionary ? May be good thing to solve it before ?

Comment: i get it by regex and it's not possible to solve it before.

Answer (score 0):

You may

- pair the first half (`raw[:len(raw) // 2]`) with the second half (`raw[len(raw) // 2:]`) using `zip`
- then  take the `Host` from one (`d1['Host']`), and the `Url` from the other (`d2['Url']`)

```
raw = [{'Host': 'dailymotion', 'Url': ''},
       {'Host': 'youtube', 'Url': ''},
       {'Host': 'Vimeo', 'Url': ''},
       {'Host': '', 'Url': 'https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox'},
       {'Host': '', 'Url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0'},
       {'Host': '', 'Url': 'https://vimeo.com/42399207'}]

result = [{'Host': d1['Host'], 'Url': d2['Url']}
          for d1, d2 in zip(raw[:len(raw) // 2], raw[len(raw) // 2:])]
print(result)
```

Comment: it works thanks @azro, someone has an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
lst = [
    {"Host": "dailymotion", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "youtube", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "Vimeo", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://vimeo.com/42399207"},
]

hosts = [d["Host"] for d in lst if d["Host"] != ""]
urls = [d["Url"] for d in lst if d["Url"] != ""]

out = [{"Host": h, "Url": u} for h, u in zip(hosts, urls)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"Host": "dailymotion", "Url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox"},
    {"Host": "youtube", "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0"},
    {"Host": "Vimeo", "Url": "https://vimeo.com/42399207"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which works even if order of elements in your list is changed:

```
data = [
    {"Host": "dailymotion", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "youtube", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "Vimeo", "Url": ""},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox"},
    {"Host": "", "Url": "https://vimeo.com/42399207"},
]

hosts = [host['Host'] for host in data if host["Host"]]
urls = [host['Url'] for host in data if host["Url"]]
out = []
for host in hosts:
    for url in urls:
        if host.lower() in url.lower():
            out.append({"Host": host, "Url": url})
            break
print (out)
```

Output:

```
[{'Host': 'dailymotion', 'Url': 'https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x37j4ox'}, {'Host': 'youtube', 'Url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDLQfA2o0'}, {'Host': 'Vimeo', 'Url': 'https://vimeo.com/42399207'}]
```